# Google App engine end points in Java

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

For one of my Android app, I had to do a simple compute from Backend. So without much research I ended up using Google AppEngine (Endpoints), since it was simple and could be easily built with my Android app (in Android Studio itself). The end point API is a very simple low compute API which will be called maybe a few hundred times a day.
Now I got the rudest shock of my life.
I got a bill of 500$ for Google App Engine, and I was billed for over 8600 hours for 30 days period. Even if I ran my server for 30x24 hours it would be 720 hours.

How is this possible?
What did I do wrong?

```
/**
 * An endpoint class we are exposing
 */
@Api(
        name = "pushApi",
        version = "v3",
        namespace = @ApiNamespace(
                ownerDomain = "com.example.sample",
                ownerName = "com.example.sample",
                packagePath = ""
        )
)
public class MyEndpoint {
    PushBean response = new PushBean();
    /**
     * A simple endpoint method that takes a name and says Hi back
     */
    @ApiMethod(name = "pushToTopic")
    public PushBean toTopic(@Named("topic") String topic, @Named("dataJson") String dataJson) {
        try{
            response.messageTopic(topic,dataJson);
            return response;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is the entry class for the Endpoint.

Comment: I think this question is not suitable to be on SO. Since you have clearly mentioned that you didn't do enough research beforehand, it's likely that you haven't done your homework yet. Without knowing your usage it's hard for us to answer. If possible could you show us the dump of your usage?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You may be able to export the usage report for `Google Compute Engine` see [Viewing Usage Report for Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/usage-export) or there are links on left side bar which could be what you are looking for. Give them a try.

Comment: The 8600 hours could be the sum of multiple machines running at the same time.

Comment: @SergeHendrickx I have edited the answer and that is the entry class for my Backend API. How does it spawn multiple instances?